# .htaccess - Forward domain with masking without using iframe

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I own two domains. [domain.com](http://www.domain.com) is for my main website, and [anotherdomain.com](http://www.anotherdomain.com) is just a vanity URL. How can I forward users to [domain.com](http://www.domain.com) when they type in [anotherdomain.com](http://www.anotherdomain.com) while keeping [anotherdomain.com](http://www.anotherdomain.com) in the URL bar? I have control of both domains and I don't want to use an iframe. Is this possible?

Both domains are on the same server. To continue the example, the root for [domain.com](http://www.domain.com) is /home/domain/ and the root for [anotherdomain.com](http://www.anotherdomain.com) is /home/anothdom/

Comment: Are both domains parked on the same server? If so, where are the document roots for each domain? Are they the same?

Comment: I've added more information to answer your questions. Thanks!

Comment: If you have control over both domains and they're on the same server, and you want it so when you go to `anotherdomain.com` it gets served content from `domain.com`, why not just change the document root to /home/domain?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I had no idea that was possible. If you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over both domains and they're on the same server, and you want it so when you go to `anotherdomain.com` it gets served content from `domain.com`, why not just change the document root to `/home/domain`?

In the event that you need special content for one domain and not the other, you can do some simple routing with htaccess (by matching against `%{HTTP_HOST}`).